# Select a value from a Drop Down List and show all the info related to that selected value in a repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down list and a repeater control.I have already populated the drop down list with the department names from the database. I am battling to select a department from the drop down list and let all the employees from that department get displayed in the repeater control.Any help would be appreciated.

This is my drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drplstDepartment" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drplstDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">       
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is my repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                            <%--<p>All The Data Is Shown</p>--%>
                    <table class="table table-default table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
                        <tr style="text-align:center;">
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Cost Centre</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Surname</th>
                            <th>ID Number</th>
                            <th>Clock Number</th>
                            <th>Date Tested</th>
                            <th>Next Due Date</th>
                            <th>ECG</th>
                            <th>Lung Function</th>
                            <th>Hearing Test</th>
                            <th>Eye Test</th>
                            <th>Other Problems</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                        </tr>                   

                </HeaderTemplate>


                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("LongDescription") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Code") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("FirstName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("LastName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("EmployeeID") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Code") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Date tested]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Next Due date]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[ECG]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Lungfunction]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Hearing Test]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Eye Test]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Other Problems]") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("[Notes]") %></td>
                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>

                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>



            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: where is C# code that your are executing on drplstDepartment selected index change event

Comment: See answer below for vb.net Back End Code @Kevin Shah

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to populate my drop down list

```
Protected Sub FillWithDepartments()

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("server=XX; Integrated Security = true")
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Departments Order By LongDescription ASC", conn)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(tbl)
    drplstDepartment.DataSource = tbl
    drplstDepartment.DataTextField = "LongDescription"
    drplstDepartment.DataValueField = "Code"
    drplstDepartment.DataBind()

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

This my code that i wish to populate my repeater control from the selected text/value from the drop down list

```
  Protected Sub drplstDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim connString As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LumotechPortal.My.MySettings.GuHR_Data").ToString())

        connString.Open()

        Dim cmdText = "select * from [EmployeeMedicalTest] WHERE (LongDescription = @LongDescription)"

        Dim Data = New DataTable()
        Dim Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connString)
        Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LongDescription", drplstDepartment.SelectedValue)
        Adapter.Fill(Data)
        Repeater1.DataSource = Data
        Repeater1.DataBind()

        connString.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: did you get any error while binding data to repeater?

Comment: No, there is just no results returning when i select an item from the drop down list. @Kevin Shah

Comment: have you check by putting break point on drplstDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: No I have not, i think I will try it out and have a look. @Kevin Shah

Answer (score 0):

Comments in line.

```
Protected Sub drplstDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Data = New DataTable()
    'connString is a poor name for a connection
    'connString implies Connection String and a connection is not a String it has a ConnectionString property
    'call it cn or con or conn
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LumotechPortal.My.MySettings.GuHR_Data").ToString())
        'Pass the query string and the connection directly to the constructor of the command
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from EmployeeMedicalTest WHERE Code = @Code;", cn)
            'Remember that you set the drplstDepartment.DataValueField = "Code"
            'I am guessing at the datatype, check your database
            'Always use .Add instead of .AddWithValue
            'It will save you from type mismatches
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(drplstDepartment.SelectedValue)
            Data.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using 'closes and disposes Command
    End Using 'closes and disposes Connection
    Repeater1.DataSource = Data
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub
```